# perl redirection linux

Tags: perl

```
sub cdevice{
    $p=$_[0];
    $s=$_[1];
    $q=$_[2];
    try {
        $device_create_cmd ="create type:NSR Device;media type:adv_file;name:$p;device access information:$p";
        system("echo $device_create_cmd > command.txt  ");
    } catch Error with {
        print "Error  " ;
        exit();     
    };
}
cdevice("/device1","raddh054","/device1");
```

this pl file is working fine on Windows but not on Linux  because echo in Linux is not accepting spaces between the text !how do i resolve it

Comment: its showing empty file in linux

Comment: You need to add single or double quotes like this system("echo \"$device_create_cmd\" > command.txt  ");

Comment: but that will not work on windows then  it produces extra quotes ...

Comment: It's not the spaces, it's the semi-colons.

Answer (score 4):

Simply open the file and write into it yourself. Why involve the shell at all?

```
use strictures;
use autodie qw(:all);

⋮

sub cdevice {
    my ($p, $s, $q) = @_;
    try {
        open my $h, '>', 'command.txt';
        print {$h} "create type:NSR Device;media type:adv_file;name:$p;device access information:$p\n"
    } …
```